# What is the difference with all the different types of .tar archives?

Tags: filemanager, tar

Could anyone tell me what is up with so many archives, and how are they differ?

There's at least five that I can think of, `.tar.tz`, `.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2`, `.tar.lz`, `.tar.z`

Which is best for what applications? It just seems silly to make so many variations of the same file but I'm sure there's a reason.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `.gz`, `.xz`, `.bz2`, `.7z`, `.lz`, `.z` suffixes are used to make clear that the file is compressed with said compression algorithm. Its use is not limited to `.tar` files, you will also see files such as `initrd.gz` (an compressed initial ramdisk) or `manual.txt.gz` (for a compressed text document). You may also see `file.tgz` which is also indicates a gzip-compressed tarball (like `file.tar.gz`).

The file extension is a convention, it does not necessarily describe the file contents. To check what kind of file you are handling, use the `file` command. Example:

```
$ file data.tar.gz
data.tar.gz: gzip compressed data, from Unix
$ gunzip -c data.tar.gz | file -
/dev/stdin: POSIX tar archive (GNU)
```

In my experience, gzip-compressed files (`.gz`) are the most common ones. It is fast in compressing and decompressing, though there are other algorithms that yield better compression ratios.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the @Lekensteyn answer, I'd like to add that this behavior is based on [Do one thing and do it well](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy) philosophy - `tar` program knows how to put multiple files into a single stream (with `.tar` extension), `gzip` knows how to compress a single file (adding `.gz` extension)*. By combining those tools you can create a command which compresses multiple files into a single `.tag.gz` file.

This approach is very flexible - you can combine a few standard Unix commands to do all sorts of things. For example, if you write a better program to compress files you don't need to modify `tar` to enable it to create `.tar.mymegazip` files - instead, you just pipe `tar`'s output to your compressor.

Similarly, `tar` knows nothing about SSH, but by combining commands you can create a script which archives files, uploads them to a remote machine via SSH and un-archives them there.

Compare this to `zip` command, which did not originate in Unix - it has built-in tools to compress whole directories, encrypt files, split the archive into smaller zipfiles etc.

---

(footnote) - yes, `tar` is able to gzip or bzip files itself using `-z` and `-j` switches, they were added for convenience, and GNU tar is actually spawning `gzip` or `bzip2` as a new process.

Comment: Example: the commands `tar c dir/ | gzip > dir.tar.gz` and `tar czf dir.tar.gz dir/` commands do the same thing. An example where `tar` is combined with SSH and `tar` (again): `tar cz Documents/ | ssh user@host 'tar xz` (rsync equivalent would be: `rsync -a Documents user@host:`)